# Pending synonyms page needs one more space

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tag-synonyms, spelling

There is no space between sentences on the [pending synonyms page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) (in case of absence votable tags):

> [image: No space]

Same content for that page can be achieved opening the mentioned link in browser's private mode.

Comment: I wonder if a newline is meant to be there. Here's what [that would look like](https://i.imgur.com/2veulAo.png).

Comment: @Spevacus vertical space is space too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed (line break added between the sentences).

> tag synonyms page
> none to see, not qualified?
> line break added now